# Angular 1 routing with template URL to html files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a litte problem with routing again.

I want to use angular routing but content of page no in "template" but link to html file.

What I have:

```
    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            template: "<h1>Index</h1>"
        })
        .when("/about", {
            templateUrl: "abc.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });
});
```

And "templateUrl" doesn't work.
It throws: `Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: abc.html (HTTP status: -1 )`

I use `<div data-ng-view></div>`

Path to "abc.html" is

```
root
    index.html
    scripts
           app.js
           config.js
           abc.html
```

So I use `scripts/abc.html` and "`abc.html`" and it do not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that angular can't locate your abc.html page. Is it in the root folder? if its in /templates/abc.html try putting that in "templateUrl" – jarasss just now   edit

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax should be:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            template: "<h1>Index</h1>"
        })
        .when("/about", {
            templateUrl: "scripts/abc.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });
});
```

When you are using the `templateUrl` you will have to add the relative path to the html.

Make sure that the html page exists in your path.

Comment: @Nerf You will have to use : `scripts/abc.html`